# Check if last item inserted exists through map key

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

```
#include <map>

struct X {
    int x;

    bool operator < (const X v) const
    {
        return (x < v.x);
    }
};

struct Y {
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    X x = {1};
    Y y = {2};

    std::map <X, Y> Z;
    std::pair<std::map<X, Y>::iterator,bool> lastval;

    // Insert a value
    lastval = Z.insert(std::pair<X, Y>(x, y));

    // Erase the "last" inserted item
    Z.erase(lastval.first->first);

    // Error: Check if last item was erased or if iterator is valid
    if (lastval.first != Z.end())
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

I get an error while checking if the last inserted item was erased. Is there any way to check for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the return value from [`map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)

```
if(Z.erase(lastval.first->first))
{
    /* item has been erased */
}
```

or

```
// Erase the "last" inserted item
Z.erase(lastval.first->first);

if(Z.find(x) == Z.end())
{
    /* item has been erased */
}
```

You should also change your `operator<` to

```
bool operator < (const X& v) const
//                      ^
//           take arg by reference to avoid unnecessary copying
```